# Mongo DB remove nested object

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I want to remove  a data in the my document. I bolded the id I want to remove

My Code like that but "This code deletes all KeyResultActions with same Id";

```
var filter = builder.Eq("Id", ObjectId.Parse(objectiveId))
                             & builder.Eq("KeyResults.Id", ObjectId.Parse(keyResultId))
                             & builder.Eq("KeyResults.KeyResultActions.Id", ObjectId.Parse(actionId));

  var update = Builders<Objective>.Update.PullFilter("KeyResults.$[].KeyResultActions",
                    Builders<KeyResultAction>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, ObjectId.Parse(actionId)));
```

**My document like that;**

```
{
    "_id": "**6311d1612559020ef536cb6f**",
    "KeyResults": [
        {
            "_id": "6311d1612559020ef536cb69",
            "Title": "Test KeyResult -1 ",
            "Description": "Test KeyResult Desc -1",
            "KeyResultActions": [
                {
                    "_id": "630f5d4ebb4428127b11fb8e"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "630f5d4ebb4428127b11fb8f"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "**6311d1612559020ef536cb6b**",
            "Title": "Test KeyResult -2",
            "Description": "Test KeyResult Desc -2",
            "KeyResultActions": [
                {
                    "_id": "**630f5d4ebb4428127b11fb8e**"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "630f5d4ebb4428127b11fb8f"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `$[]` all positional operator which will remove the first item from the `KeyResultActions` array for all items in the `KeyResults`.

Instead, replace it with [`$` positional operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which selects the first matched element in the array.

> MongoDB query

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "6311d1612559020ef536cb6f",
  "KeyResults._id": "6311d1612559020ef536cb6b",
  "KeyResults.KeyResultActions._id": "630f5d4ebb4428127b11fb8e"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "KeyResults.$[].KeyResultActions": {
      _id: "630f5d4ebb4428127b11fb8e"
    }
  }
})
```

> MongoDB .NET Driver syntax

```cs
var update = Builders<Objective>.Update.PullFilter("KeyResults.$.KeyResultActions",
    Builders<KeyResultAction>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, ObjectId.Parse(actionId)));
```

> Demo

[image]